# shortcuts for editing code indentation in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Are there any shortcuts for code indentation editing in a jupyter notebook like available in VScode, sublime, etc? 
Specifically, I need help for shifting back a selected piece of code by one tab space.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
Ctrl-] : indent
Ctrl-[ : shifting back indentation
```

if it doesn't work, then try：

```
Tab : indent
Shift + Tab : shfting back indentation
```

Answer (score 4):

just select and drag from the beginning of the code piece until the line you wish for while holding `alt` to choose multiple indexes at multiple lines (or you can use it for rectangular selection too)

after that `tab` for right indentation and `shift+tab` for left indentation

Comment: Nice enough, this is the same for colab!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how it works in VScode, but for indentation in Jupyter Notebook you just have to mark the line/lines that you want to intend and then press `SHIFT`+`TAB` for back shifting the indentation or `TAB` for indentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can select the code block using `Ctrl + A` and then use

```
Ctrl + ] indent
Ctrl + [ dedent
```

For complete list of Jupyter notebook key shortcuts visit [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/jypyter-notebook-shortcuts-bf0101a98330)